# When I use CascadingValue it always says the same error csharp(CS1003)

Tags: c#, blazor

I just started learning blazor so I am with the official documentation from Microsoft, In a point it explains how to share information by using cascading parameters. At the example it says what to write. So I copied but I can't continue bc it always says this error on the "Value = Throwback Thursday". I already tried to restart vscode and cleared the cache.

```cs
@page "/specialoffers"

<h1>Special Offers</h1>

<CascadingValue Name="DealName" Value="Throwback Thursday">
    <!-- Any descendant component rendered here will be able to access the cascading value. -->
</CascadingValue>
```

The name 'Thursday' doesn't exists on the actual context [BlazingPizza]csharp(CS0103)

Answer (score 2):

Blazor parameters are [not always strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) like regular HTML, try this:

```
<CascadingValue Name="DealName" Value="@("Throwback Thursday")">
```